# Can't get AnimatePresence in Framer Motion to work

Tags: framer-motion

I've been trying to get <AnimatePresence> from Framer Motion to work. But for some reason, I can't get it to work. I want to have an exit animation for a mobile navbar.

Here's a screenshot of the code:
[image]

Here's the animation variables:
[image]

It animates when en entering the DOM, but there's no animation when it leaves. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I've tried moving the different components around, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Framer docs](https://www.framer.com/docs/animate-presence/##unmount-animations):

> Child `motion` components must each have a unique `key` prop so
> `AnimatePresence` can track their presence in the tree.

You need to add a unique `key` prop to your `m.ul` element.

Comment: I thought that only applied when mapping children. I tried adding a key="3218903218" <- random string to the m.ul, but it didn't seem to make a difference. Did I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: Oh, you also have the exit animation set to `show`. You probably want `hide`?

Comment: Ah, yes! I just tried that to see if it made a difference. It doesn't work either way. Whenever I remove the nav from the dom, it instantly disappears

Comment: Are you importing `domAnimation`? The `m` package doesn’t include exit animations by default. https://www.framer.com/docs/guide-reduce-bundle-size/#how-to-reduce-bundle-size

Comment: Oh my, god, I'm stupid. Thank you so much for the generous help, Cadin! Have a nice day